# Why does cigarette smoke stay so stubbornly on our bodies?

Tags: everyday-life, physical-chemistry, biology

How does anything stick to anything, for that matter?

Another example: why does perfume also stay so stubbornly on our bodies? And why do some perfumes stay longer than others on a fundamental level?

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Chemistry.SE would be a better place to have this question answered, as per @rob comment. But basically, just about all surfaces have *pores.* Human skin is porous, as are surfaces made of cement, wood, plaster etc. Because they are porous, they are _absorbent._ That is, particles in things like cigarette smoke, perfume etc., will easily sit in these pores therefore leaving a lingering odor.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Cigarette smoke consists of tiny particles with rough surfaces. they will naturally get tangled up in any other rough surface like that of a piece of cotton fabric.

Because they are rich in partially-burned hydrocarbons, they will stick like glue to other hydrocarbon-rich surfaces like fabric, plastic or painted wood or metal. In fact, once stuck to such a surface, the hydrocarbons in the particle will actually diffuse into the solid plastic or paint surface and stay there practically forever, slowly diffusing out over time and polluting the air with cigarette smell no matter how vigorously you scrub the surface with soap.

To get rid of the smell you must repaint the surfaces with a barrier paint that blocks the diffusion of the hydrocarbons. In the case of fabrics like drapes, they must be discarded and replaced with new.